# HTML/jQuery or JSP script

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsp, input

I need to define a hierarchy of tables in HTML, with input fields.

```
<table>
    <input ...>
    <table>
        <input...>
        <submit button...>
    </table>
    <table>
        <input...>
        <submit button...>
    </table>
</table>
```

How may I write a code, so when pressing one of the submit buttons all input variables from the current and parent tables are sent over ?
I want a button to fire one form, the second button another form. Different forms.

---

I need two distinct forms, one for the first button, another for the second.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole `<table>` in a `<form>` if you want everything to be submitted.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question. Please comment if I did. I will change my answer if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the parent and current table , to wrap up the table inside another you just need to arrive in this way ,

```
<form action="" method="">    
<table>
 <tr>
   <td><input /> </td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><input /> </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**And this form holds the inputs from both the tables , so that you might access them in the next `jsp` or `servlet`**

Hope this helps !!